# Summing row values using mutate_at

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr, summary

I am trying to sum row values by specific columns using `mutate_at` and `sum` function. The dataset is given below:

```
Country/Region   1/22/20   1/23/20   1/24/20  1/25/20  1/26/20  1/27/20 
Chili            0         0         0        3        1        2
Chili            1         0         1        4        2        1
China            23        26        123      12       56       70
China            45        25        56       23       16       18
```

I am using following code but instead of summing all the column values, I am getting zeroes.

```
tb <- confirmed_raw %>% group_by(`Country/Region`) %>%
      filter(`Country/Region` != "Cruise Ship") %>%
      select(-`Province/State`, -Lat, -Long) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~sum)
```

The output which I want is:

```
Country/Region   1/22/20   1/23/20   1/24/20  1/25/20  1/26/20  1/27/20 
Chili            2         0         1        7        3        3
China            68        51        179      35       72       88
```

But instead of above, all the date columns are coming 0. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `summarise_all` instead of `mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~sum)`?

```
tb %>% group_by(`Country.Region`) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

PS: I guess you have few typos here such as `tb[1,1]` should return `1`, not `2`. Also, the example code does not correspond to the data entirely (ther is no `Cruise Ship` or `Province/State` in it. Still, ignoring those, I found this works to generate the expected output.

Comment: Thanks very much. summarise_all worked and gave desired output. And yes tb[1,1] is a typo and I have given only a part of my dataset for simplicity. Actual dataset does contains "Cruise Ship" and "Province/State". Actual dataset is the JHU dataset for COVID19.

Comment: Glad to help, I also learn in this way. Would you please accept and upvote answers? In that way, we know that the problem solved and we get points too :D

Answer (score 1):

To complete, another option :

```
tb %>% group_by(`Country/Region`) %>% mutate_all(sum) %>% distinct(`Country/Region`,.keep_all = TRUE)
```